# Access vue from imported file

Tags: javascript, node.js, laravel, vuejs2, element-ui

I'm trying to access my Vue element from a `require`d javascript file but i've failed so far... I want to take element-ui's `el-form-item` component's rule validator from outside. Maybe my logic is wrong but this way should work too (*i guess*)

> Vue@2.5.13
>   element-ui@2.0.11
>   npm@5.6.0

---

## Vue.use(...)

I tried `Vue.use(...)`
My javascript file.

```
const MyPlugin = {
    install(Vue, options) {
        Vue.prototype.usernameValidator = function (rule, value, callback) {
            console.log(Vue);
            console.log(this);
            // ...
```

My console output:

**console.log(Vue);**

> ƒ Vue$3(options) {
>    if ("development" !== 'production' &&
>      !(this instanceof Vue$3)
>    ) {
>      warn('Vue is a constructor and should be called with the `new` keyword');
>    }
>    this._init(options);
>   }

**console.log(this);**

> {"required":true,"field":"username","fullField":"username","type":"string"...}

---

## beforeCreate

```
module.exports = function (rule, value, callback) {
    console.log(this)
    // ...
});
```

**console.log(this);**

> {"required":true,"field":"username","fullField":"username","type":"string"...}

---

As I said my logic may wrong but I'm just curious can I make a method like this ?

Regards

---

---

## Update

I'm calling it in `register.blade.php`

```
<el-form-item label="Username" prop="username" :rules="[{required:true, validator: usernameValidator, trigger:'blur,change'}]">
    <el-input v-model="form.username" name="username"></el-input>
</el-form-item>
```

In `app.js`;

```
Vue.use(require('./plugins/usernameValidator'));
// ...
window.app = new Vue({
    // ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Where are you `require`ing the element? I'll detail out how I generally create plugins using your examples.

Define a plugin:

```
// my-plugin.js
import {FormItem} from 'element-ui'

const MyPlugin = {
    install(Vue, options) {
        Vue.prototype.usernameValidator = function (rule, value, callback) {
            // use FormItem's validator
```

Then register the plugin via `Vue.use`:

```
// app.js
import MyPlugin from 'my-plugin'
// or require 
const MyPlugin = require('my-plugin')

Vue.use(MyPlugin)
```

Later in a component, call the `usernameValidator` method defined in the plugin:

```
<template>
     <input name="username" v-model="username" :class="isValidUsername ? 'borderGreen' : 'borderRed'" />
     <div>{{ usernameFeedback }}</div>
</template>

export default {
    beforeCreate () {
          // what would you validate in here?
          // this.usernameValidator(rule, value, callback)
    },
    data () {
        return {
             username: null,
             usernameFeedback: null
        }
    },
    computed: {
        isValidUsername () {
              // assuming the validator returns a boolean, valid/invalid
              return this.usernameValidator(rule, this.username, this.validationCallback)
        }
    },
    methods: {
        validationCallback (feedback) {
             this.usernameFeedback = feedback
        }
    }
}
```

If you have an example of how you `require` a component I can update my answer, but as it is you can access the plugin method in a component using `this`.

Comment: Hi, sorry for late reply. I'm require'ing like `Vue.use(require('./plugins/usernameValidator'));` but I think you need to know element-ui to reply my question. Thanks

Comment: I'm quite familiar with element UI, as well as a number of other UI libraries.  I just noticed a few things in your post that didn't make sense in terms of your question. Maybe that's just me though. Ta.

Comment: Updated question. If any information is need to help my problem please tell me... and thanks again :]